Scraping content using selenium from a website using for loop in python
I am new at python and selenium. I am trying to webscrape text from the website audible.in/search using for loop. Below is the code written.
I was running the following code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

web = "https://www.audible.in/search"
path = "C:/Users/vikas/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(web)

container = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "adbl-    impression-container "))
products = WebDriverWait(container, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "./div/span/ul/li")))

book_title = []
book_author = []
book_length = []

for product in products:
    book_title.append(product.find_element("xpath",'//h3[contains(@class, "bc-heading")]').text)
    book_author.append(product.find_element("xpath",'//a[contains(@href, "author")]').text)
    book_length.append(product.find_element("xpath",'//li[contains(@class, "runtimeLabel")]').text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'title':book_title, 'author':book_author, 'length':book_length})
df.to_csv('books.csv')

When I run the code I am expecting to append all the h3, a and li in the loop to the list. There are total 20 elements. What I am getting is the first element 20 times. What is that I am doing wrong here. Kindly help.

If your Python and selenium versions are up-to-date (3.12.4 and 4.22.0 respectively) you no longer need to specify a path to your Chrome driver executable.
I would also suggest a different approach to navigating the web page as follows:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.audible.in/search"

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")


def fr(e: WebElement, s: str, r: str) -> str:
    return e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, s).text.replace(r, "").strip()


with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get(URL)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    ec = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located
    db = {"Title": [], "Author": [], "Duration": []}
    for li in wait.until(ec((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.productListItem"))):
        db["Title"].append(li.get_attribute("aria-label"))
        db["Author"].append(fr(li, "li.bc-list-item.authorLabel", "Written by:"))
        db["Duration"].append(fr(li, "li.bc-list-item.runtimeLabel", "Length:"))
    print(pd.DataFrame(db).to_string(index=False))

Output:
                                           Title                  Author           Duration
                    War of Lanka (Hindi Edition)          Amish Tripathi 17 hrs and 15 mins
                    Panchatantra (Hindi Edition)           Vishnu Sharma  5 hrs and 41 mins
                               Forge Your Future          A. P. J. Kalam  5 hrs and 37 mins
                                       Meri Gita       Devdutt Pattanaik  7 hrs and 39 mins
            Kautilya Arthshastra (Hindi Edition)                Chanakya              6 hrs
        41 Anmol Kahaniya [41 Priceless Stories]               Premchand 15 hrs and 28 mins
               The Guy Next Door (Hindi Edition)                 Nylla C 36 hrs and 43 mins
                     Kalki Puran (Hindi Edition)               Dr. Vinay  6 hrs and 10 mins
    The Quick and Easy Way to Effective Speaking           Dale Carnegie  6 hrs and 39 mins
                           Jadugarni [Sorceress]   Surender Mohan Pathak  8 hrs and 24 mins
21 Shreshth Kahaniyan Prem Chand (Hindi Edition)        Munshi Premchand  7 hrs and 44 mins
                                            Gita                  Pranay  4 hrs and 40 mins
                           The Path to Self-Love               Ruby Dhal  6 hrs and 55 mins
                   The Art of Influencing People         Virender Kapoor            38 mins
                            Haar Jeet [Lose Win]   Surender Mohan Pathak  8 hrs and 34 mins
              The Sandman, Act I (Hindi Edition) Neil Gaiman, Dirk Maggs  11 hrs and 3 mins
                       The Housemaid Is Watching         Freida McFadden 11 hrs and 42 mins
              Red Circle Society (Hindi Edition)   Surender Mohan Pathak  3 hrs and 15 mins
                             Pride and Prejudice             Jane Austen 11 hrs and 35 mins
                   Crystal Lodge (Hindi Edition)   Surender Mohan Pathak 11 hrs and 49 mins

